# Parameterizing deviation from average

Tags: standard-deviation, binary-data

I am seeking help in parameterizing a concept.

For instance:
"Interest in literature" may be higher for poorer book owners than book owners with higher income, given that book ownership is only 10% in low income population in comparison to 90% in high income population.

I would like to parameterize as ordinal variable "Interest in literature", using two variables, book ownership (binary) and income (continuous).

Any suggestions or reference for doing this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any data?  Could you describe them?  Exactly what do you mean by "parameterize"?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I can't share the data, but the data is from a survey of +10000 people that answered book ownership (y/n) income level ($, or wealth quantile). By parameterize I meant to derive a new variable/index from the two variables (book ownership & income level) to represent ~"interest in literature". Under the assumption that "book ownership" is linearly proportional to "income", book owners in low income quantile would have high "Interest in literature" in comparison to book owners in high income quantile.

Comment: I am hoping to use the degree that a sample deviates from the mean (poor book owners (10%) deviate from the majority of the poor population (90%) that don't own a book) to measure the "interest in literature". I hope this clarifies.